# loop through checkboxes - how to get all checked checkboxes?

Tags: php, loops, checkbox

I have the following group of checkboxes:

```
<div class="chb_group">
   <span class="custom_chb_wrapper">
       <input class="zcheckbox" type="checkbox" value="164" name="categoriesfilters">
       <label>Air Condition A/C</label>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="chb_group">
    <span class="custom_chb_wrapper">
        <input class="zcheckbox" type="checkbox" value="165" name="categoriesfilters">
        <label>Clima</label>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="chb_group">
    <span class="custom_chb_wrapper">
        <input class="zcheckbox" type="checkbox" value="166" name="categoriesfilters">
        <label>Range Command</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is just a part from very long form. I am trying to loop trough the checkboxes with the name categoriesfilters and to get the values of  the checked checkboxes that belong in this group.

I am trying with following code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $name=>$value) {
                    if($name == 'categoriesfilters') {
                    echo $name . " -> ".$value ."<br />";
                    }
                 }
```

but i am getting only the last checkbox even i check all of them. Anyone can help?

Regards, John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change inputs' `name` to `name="categoriesfilters[]"`

Then you can access `categoriesfilters` values with `$_POST['categoriesfilters']`

Remember that `$_POST['categoriesfilters']` is an array of integers, so:

```
foreach ($_POST as $name=>$value) {
  if ($name == 'categoriesfilters') {
    echo $name . " -> ". implode(',', $value) ."<br />";
  }
}
```